# IntelliJ 2016.2 - JSON Schema Validation

Tags: json, intellij-idea, jsonschema

I have configured intelliJ for JSON Schema.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/json-schema.html

such that my valid JSON schema *should* check JSON against it - however if I write invalid json (syntactically correct, not semantically against schema) intelliJ does not detect this, just indicates it is valid?

Any ideas?

Also is there a short cut key(s) to trigger schema validation of a given file?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't found any shortcut to trigger JSON scheme validation. It works the same way as checking of programming code - some kind of background task. I don't have a problem with JSON scheme validation in 2017.1 EAP (i.e. I can see JSON errors and scheme errors). However, you can always close the file and reopen it (that's what works for me mostly)

Comment: What works for me is to press `Ctrl-Alt-S` and go to settings, navigate to the JSON Schemas Tab, not change anything and just select OK, changes to my schema always seem to reflect right after I do that.

Comment: What about Android Studio (v3)? It seems it doesn't work.

Comment: As of intellij IDEA 2017.3, json files have an icon on the right-upper side to show green-tick or red-tick due to auto-validation.